# How to predict the test set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, dataset, one-hot-encoding

I'm following the Kaggle's course section step by step. There is something that I couldn't figure it out.. I'm trying to predict my model but it doesn't work, I've searched some topics but couldn't find anything useful..here's the last part of the code;

```
final_encoder =OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
final_X_train = pd.DataFrame(final_encoder.fit_transform(X_train[low_cardinality_cols]))
final_X_valid = pd.DataFrame(final_encoder.transform(X_valid[low_cardinality_cols]))
```

One-hot encoding removed index; put it back

```
final_X_train.index =X_train.index
final_X_valid.index =X_valid.index
```

Remove categorical columns (will replace with one-hot encoding)

```
num_X_train = X_train.drop(object_cols, axis=1)
num_X_valid = X_valid.drop(object_cols, axis=1)
```

Add one-hot encoded columns to numerical features

```
final_2_X_train =pd.concat([num_X_train, final_X_train], axis=1)
final_2_X_valid =pd.concat([num_X_valid, final_X_valid], axis=1)`
```

until here there is no problem.. but when I run this part;

```
final_X_test =pd.DataFrame(final_encoder.transform(X_test))

preds_test = final_X_test`
```

I have an error :: `ValueError: Input contains NaN`

also the things that I've searched on github and stackoverflow didn't work.. any idea?
by the way, if you'd like to see full code: https://www.kaggle.com/ugurlumucahit/exercise-categorical-variables

Comment: I encountered the same issue in that dataset. Deleting and creating a new notebook solved my problem.

Comment: I'll definetly try that.. thanks

Comment: What did you try to address the fact that there are missing values in your data?